# Device to small to write image of same device created with dd back to device using win10 image writer echer

Tags: linux, windows-10, dd

on a raspberry pi running buster i create a backup image of a raspberry pi 32 Gb SD card with the command

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=//NAS/backup.img bs=1M conv=sync,noerror iflag=fullblock
```

the result file is 29,7 GB (31.915.507.712 bytes)

when i try to use balena etcher to write this file back to the SAME SD card, etcher tells me the SD card is to small. i am told i need additional 512 mb.

how to resolve this?

any advice is welcome.

Comment: Maybe when writing back, change `bs=1M` to `bs=512c` will work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think stackoverflow is the right place for this question, there is also Linux stackexchange which would be more suited for this question.

But from my experience I think dd does not create images in the same way that rasperry images are created (if that makes sense). So in short you can't use balena etcher to restore the image, a friend if mine tried the same and failed.

So I would advice you to just live boot a linux and from there run the dd command to restore the image onto the sdcard. Maybe even the windows subsytem would also work but I didn't try so live usb stick would be the best I think.